# Confused about what is continous integration

Tags: continuous-integration

So in my previous company the work flow would have been like:

1. Create a ticket in Gitlab.
2. Someone working on the ticket creates a branch where they put their changes. Then they make a merge request when done.
3. Someone else reviews the code then merges it into master.

Under CI, does it mean that you are just checking your code directly to master at the end of the day? Even when you haven't finished the ticket?

EDIT: Here's what I read:

> "CI developers integrate all their work into trunk (also known as
> mainline or master) on a regular basis (at least daily)."

https://techbeacon.com/devops/are-you-really-doing-continuous-integration-heres-how-tell

> Continuous Integration applies a different trigger for integration -
> you integrate whenever you've made a hunk of progress on the feature
> and your branch is still healthy. There's no expectation that the
> feature be complete, just that there's been a worthwhile amount of
> changes to the codebase. The rule of thumb is that "everyone commits
> to the mainline every day", or more precisely: you should never have
> more than a day's work sitting unintegrated in your local repository.
> In practice, most practitioners of Continuous Integration integrate
> many times a day, happy to integrate an hour's worth of work or less.

Source: https://martinfowler.com/articles/branching-patterns.html

Comment: There are _many_ articles on the internet. What remains unclear, after reading a few? https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+continous+integration&oq=what+is+continous+integration There should be discussion of _automated tools_ (performing various tasks such as building, running tests, eg). The “at the end of the day” is both limiting and largely irrelevant given branching models.

Comment: For example: In the projects I work on, basic CI automation is applied to _all_ branches whenever they are pushed, and feature branches are only merged into mainlines when ready. The mainlines themselves go through additional automation, whenever a branch is merged.

Comment: I've just edited my post to add some more info.

Comment: There are much _better_ articles out there — this question feels like it’s based in a poor source. One should **not** “integrate all their work into trunk (also known as mainline or master) on a regular basis (at least daily)” blindly. That’s a good (bad?) way to get incomplete junk moving upward and causing havoc. It’s 2020 and both developers and tools know, or should know, how branching models work.